# How to calculate index of dynamical system in Mathematica?

Tags: dynamic

I am brand new to Mathematica, so apologies if this is an obvious question.

**Question:** How to calculate the index of a dynamical system? (from index theory; see [here](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Evered/CourseDS2019/Tutorial%209%20-%20Index%20Theory.pdf))

**Example**: Let us say we have a dynamical system:

$$ \dot x = -x $$
$$ \dot y = -y $$

then we can plot that in Mathematica using `StreamPlot` and we can look at the phase-portrait to see that the index = 1 (for a curve taken around the whole $xy$-plane). However, is there a function that can do this index calculation for us?

**Edit:** My code for the above system was:

```
vector[x1_, x2_] := {-x1, -x2}
StreamPlot[vector[x1, x2], {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", StreamPoints -> Fine, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 StreamColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]
```

Here is the definition of an index. Let us say we have a system:

$$ \dot x_1 = f(x_1, x_2) $$
$$ \dot x_2 = g(x_1, x_2) $$

Then the vector field $ \frac{dx_2}{dx_1} = \frac{g(x_1, x_2)}{f(x_1, x_2)} $ makes an angle:

$$ \phi(x_1, x_2) = \text{arctan}\left( \frac{g(x_1, x_2)}{f(x_1, x_2)} \right) $$

to the $x_1 $ axis. Given this angle and a simple closed curve $ \Gamma $ in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, the *index* of $ \Gamma$, $I(\Gamma)$ is defined as:
$$ I(\Gamma) = \oint_{\Gamma} \frac{d\phi(x_1, x_2)}{2\pi} $$

Comment: Please include the definition of your system as Mathematica code, and a definition of the index you seek, so your question is self contained

Comment: Sure thing, has been added to question now.